# Credit card validator code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, e-commerce, checksum

I wrote a Python code that is validating Credit Card Numbers. Some of the advanced programmers told me my whole code is messy. How can I make my code cleaner?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def CheckNumber(CreditCardNumber) :
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    print("\nYour Credit Card Number is : " , CreditCardNumber , "\n")
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    CreditCardNumber = list(map(int, CreditCardNumber))
    x = len(CreditCardNumber) - 2
    y = len(CreditCardNumber) - 1
    z = 0
    WorkingList = []
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    while x >= 0 :
        WorkingList.append(CreditCardNumber[x] * 2)
        x -= 2
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    while y >= 0 :
        WorkingList.append(CreditCardNumber[y])
        y -= 2
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    WorkingListStr = list(map(str , WorkingList))
    WorkingListStr = "".join(WorkingListStr) 
    del WorkingList[:]
    while z < len(WorkingListStr) :
        WorkingList.append(WorkingListStr[z])
        z += 1
    WorkingList = list(map(int , WorkingList))
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    Mod10 = sum(WorkingList) % 10
    #------------------------------------------------------------------#
    if Mod10 == 0 :
        return True
    else :
        return False
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
CardNumber = input("Credit Card Number : ")
CheckNumberStr = str(CardNumber)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
First4 = CheckNumberStr[0] + CheckNumberStr[1] + CheckNumberStr[2] + CheckNumberStr[3]
First2 = CheckNumberStr[0] + CheckNumberStr[1]
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
if len(CheckNumberStr) > 12 and len(CheckNumberStr) < 17 :
    # "Visa Card" Checking
    if CheckNumberStr[0] == "4" :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" Visa \" Credit Card !")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" Visa \" Credit Card")
    # "MasterCard" Card Checking
    if CheckNumberStr[0] == "5" and CheckNumber[1] < "6" and CheckNumber[1] > "0" :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" MasterCard \" Credit Card")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" MasterCard \" Credit Card")
    # "Diners Club Card" Checking
    if CheckNumberStr[0] == 3 and CheckNumberStr[1] == 6 or CheckNumberStr[0] == 3 and CheckNumberStr[1] == 8 :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" Diners Club \" Credit Card")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" Diners Club \" Credit Card")
    # "Discover" Card Checking
    if First4== "6011" or First2 == "65" :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" Discover \" Credit Card")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" Discover \" Credit Card")
    # "JCB" Card Checking
    if First2 == "35" :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" JCB \" Credit Card")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" JCB \" Credit Card")
    # "American Express" Card Checking
    if First2 == "34" or First2 == "37" :
        CheckBool = CheckNumber(CheckNumberStr)
        if CheckBool == True :
            print("This is a Valid \" American Express \" Credit Card")
        else :
            print("This is not a Valid \" American Express \" Credit Card")



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
else :
    print("Sorry , but this is not a Credit Card Number !")
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having *a lot* of code duplication in the second part, for all the different card vendors. Use the different `if` blocks just to determine the vendor and store it in a variable, and then do the checking and printing afterwards.

```
number_str = input("Credit Card Number: ") # already str in Python 3

if 12 < len(number_str) < 17 :
    first2 = number_str[0:2]
    first4 = number_str[0:4]

    vendor = None
    if number_str[0] == "4" :
        vendor = "Visa"
    if number_str[0] == "5" and "0" < number_str[1] < "6":
        vendor = "MasterCard"
    if first2 in ("36", "38"):
        vendor = "Diners Club"
    if first4 == "6011" or first2 == "65":
        vendor = "Discover"
    if first2 == "35":
        vendor = "JCB"
    if first2 in ("34", "37"):
        vendor = "American Express"

    if vendor is not None:
        if check_number(number_str):
            print('This is a Valid "%s" Credit Card!' % vendor)
        else :
            print('This is not a Valid "%s" Credit Card' % vendor)
    else:
        print('Unknown vendor')
else:
    print("Sorry, but this is not a Credit Card Number!")
```

Minor points:

- use proper Python naming conventions (no upper-case variables, no camel case) so IDEs can highlight them properly
- don't compare `bool` variables to `True` or `False`
- use comparison chaining, `in`, and slicing instead of `and`
- you were comparing `int` with `str` in a few places

Alternatively, instead of all those `if` conditions, you could use a dictionary mapping regular expressions to card vendors. Example:

```
>>> vendors = {"4": "Visa", "5[1-5]": "Mastercard", "36|38": "Diners Club", 
...            "6011|65": "Discover", "35": "JCB", "34|37": "American Express"}
>>> number_str = "6011343887"
>>> next(v for k, v in vendors.items() if re.match(k, number_str))
'Discover'
```

This way, the entire block of code becomes this:

```
vendors = {"4": "Visa", 
           "5[0-6]": "Mastercard", 
           "36|38": "Diners Club", 
           "6011|65": "Discover", 
           "35": "JCB", 
           "34|37": "American Express"}

number_str = input("Credit Card Number : ")
if 12 < len(number_str) < 17 :
    try:
        vendor = next(v for k, v in vendors.items() if re.match(k, number_str))
        if check_number(number_str):
            print('This is a Valid "%s" Credit Card!' % vendor)
        else :
            print('This is not a Valid "%s" Credit Card' % vendor)
    except StopIteration:
        print('Unknown vendor')
else:
    print("Sorry, but this is not a Credit Card Number !")
```

---

For `check_digits` (aka `CheckDigits`) I'd suggest using `for` loops instead of `while`. Also, the entire `z` loop seems unneccessary, as it only converts from `int` to `str` and back to `int` to separate the digits. The same can be done using `map`. Also, you should move the `print` from inside the `check_digits` function to the main script.

```
def check_number(number) :
    number = list(map(int, number))

    digits = []
    for x in range(len(number) - 2, -1, -2):
        digits.append(number[x] * 2)
    for y in range(len(number) - 1, -1, -2):
        digits.append(number[y])

    digits = list(map(int, ''.join(map(str, digits))))
    return sum(digits) % 10 == 0
```